# How do I reset a picture's location when it gets to a certain location?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a picture's location reset when it gets to a certain location and I thought that the

```
if(x == 557 && y == 533){
  x = 300;
  y = 300;
}
```

statement would reset the x and y coordinates but I was wrong... 
Here's my code:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvasWidth = context.canvas.width, canvasHeight = context.canvas.height;
var x = 300;
var y = 300;
trash();
mrTrumpet();
function trash(){
  var trsh = new Image();
  trsh.src = "trash.png";
  trsh.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(trsh, 559, 550);
  };
};
function mrTrumpet(){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "character.png";
  img.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(img, x, y);
  };
};
function move(e){
  if(e.keyCode==68){x++};
  if(e.keyCode==65){x--};
  if(e.keyCode==87){y--};
  if(e.keyCode==83){y++};
  canvas.width=canvas.width;
  trash();
  mrTrumpet();
};
setInterval(function(){
  console.log("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
},1000);
setInterval(function(x, y){
  if(x == 557 && y == 533){
  x = 300;
   y = 300;
  };
},1000);
document.onkeydown = move;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in your second `setInterval` call are shadowing your global `x` and `y` values.

Try:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if(x == 557 && y == 533){
    x = 300;
    y = 300;
  };
}, 1000);
```

Also, you may want to check the values independently lest someone move the image WAY to the RIGHT or WAY to the BOTTOM.

```
setInterval(function(){
  if (x == 557) x = 300;
  if (y == 533) y = 300;
}, 1000);
```

This will reset your image left/top when it reaches your "edge".